# Make uniform character widths for all fonts in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, user-interface, text, settings, monospace

[image: Different font widths]

It appears that the text is no longer monospace when the fonts are mixed and matched
Here the example shows a mixture of Fira Code and Consolas for the characters that Fira Code does not support, namely "ʷ" and "ɖ". The characters are a different width than the neighbouring "d". Is there a setting to fix this?

I have tried to search the settings and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to do this, so I raised a feature-request asking for it: [Way to adjust font sizings for when multiple fonts are active #196937](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/196937). If you'd like to see it get added to the backlog, please give it a thumbs up. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like "+1" / "bump".